# Simulate upload with PrimeNG file upload component?

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng

I am trying to use the **PrimeNG file upload component** in a prototype I am making. The [demo on their page](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload) simulates the files being uploaded, with a progress bar ultimately displaying the message:

[image]

Looking at their code, they are using a file `upload.php` which is a dummy file that only contains

`<?php echo '<p>Fake Upload Process</p>'; ?>`

So, I added upload.php and I get the message in the screenshot but not the progress bar.

Looking at the TS, it looks like all that's there is:

```
onUpload(event) {
 for (const file of event.files) {
   this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
 }

 this.msgs = [];
 this.msgs.push({ severity: 'info', summary: 'File Uploaded', detail: '' });
}
```

Am I missing something?  I'm just trying to get the demo they have to run in my prototype, to simulate the UI of uploading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this implement  (onProgress)="progressReport($event)" on the p-file upload as

```
<p-fileUpload #fileuploader [customUpload]="true"  (onProgress)="progressReport($event)"
```

then in ts file, you can use get access to p-upload via @ViewChild, and then in the code where you are receiving updates of the uploaded percentage, use

```
      this.fileuploader.onProgress.emit(this.value);
```

and on the custom onProgress handler we can implement as

```
progressReport($event: any) {
    this.fileuploader.progress = $event;
}
```

This property progress is a public property I came across while searching for this feature, so this can be used to have working file upload progress bar.

If still any doubts please feel free to contact

Comment: can you pls. upload complete code for this ?